# How to strip out particular text using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have got below text as string

```
test = "<span class='convert'>USD 30</span>"
```

I need to write a function in **VBSCript** which will take above string as input and will return **USD 30** as output.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = Replace (Replace(test , "<span class='convert'>",""),"</span>","")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input text is more complicated than the example you've given, I would recommend using an XML library such as [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to parse the text. Otherwise, you can use a [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab2dx62%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```vb
Const test = "<span class='convert'>USD 30</span>"
dim regex: set regex = new RegExp
regex.pattern = ">([^<]*)"
dim matches: set matches = regex.execute(test)
dim output: output = Empty
if matches.Count <> 0 then
    output = matches(0).submatches(0)
end if
Response.Write output
```

Comment: thanks...but I am using VBScript, what language you have used above?

Comment: [vbscript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt(v=vs.85).aspx). What environment are you using? ASP, Windows Script Host?

Comment: I am using ASP, any suggestions

Comment: The only bit here that's incompatible with ASP is the `WScript.Echo` call. In ASP, you might use `Response.Write output`. What about this is causing concern?